# Excel: If A1 contains X and B1 contains Y, write 'xx' in C1

Tags: excel

I want to be able to compare two columns that contain certain text from a database and if it contains certain keywords to put 'RMA' in another cell.

Example:

```
A       B           C
[SOS]   Component   RMA
RMA                 RMA
                    Null
```

Columns A and B are already populated and I want to write 'RMA' in C.

I already have a formula in column C to find 'RMA' from column A with another search.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RMA",[@Title])),"RMA","Null"
```

([@Title] is my column 'A' in the table)

*EDIT - Cell A already contains 'RMA' and 'SOS'. I need to compare if cell A has 'SOS' AND cell B contains 'Component'. I would like to nest it in the above formula as well.

Comment: Are you looking for exact words in both, as in one each, or a list of words?

Comment: something like: **`=IF(AND(MATCH("x",A:A,0)>0,MATCH("y",B:B,0)>0),"xx","Not Found")`** ...?

Comment: I just need the words 'SOS' and 'Component' searched/filtered. Those are the common words designated in my database that I need to relate. The [] can be ignored

Comment: @ManishChristian `=IF(AND(MATCH("SOS",[@Title],0)>0,MATCH("Component",[@[Status Reason]],0)>0),"RMA","Null")` did not work. It resulted in #N/A

Comment: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SOS",[@Title])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COMPONENT",[@COLUMNBTITLE]))),"RMA","Null")`

Comment: @ScottCraner So close! Is there a way that I can nest the already "RMA" search in. What you have works great but I lose the "RMA" function I already have established

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RMA",[@Title])),AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SOS",[@Title])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COMPONENT",[@COLUMNBT‌​ITLE])))),"RMA","Null")
```

Replace `COLUMNBT‌​ITLE` with the title of column B.

Comment: That was it! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest If statements and reuse the code you already have, such as:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RMA",A1)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SOS",B1)),"Match",""),"")

Comment: I still need to search if cell B contains 'Component' though. Cell A contains text that already has RMA and SOS.